# Unresolved reference issue in PyCharm

Tags: python, ide, pycharm

I have a directory structure

```
├── simulate.py
├── src
│   ├── networkAlgorithm.py
│   ├── ...
```

And I can access the network module with `sys.path.insert()`.

```
import sys
import os.path
sys.path.insert(0, "./src")
from networkAlgorithm import *
```

However, pycharm complains that it cannot access the module. How can I teach pycham to resolve the reference?

[image]

Comment: Do src folder has `__init__.py` file?

Comment: @Puffin GDI: No, it does not.

Comment: @PuffinGDI Do src folders need this __init__.py file?

Comment: Yes in order for python to identify packages: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094723/pycharm-marking-a-folder-as-sources-root-is-not-recursive-for-subfolders/

Comment: I renamed the class name and continue working on it. When i hit run, there was this error, totally forgot  renaming and tried looking for pycharm suggestions during import. Damn, suggestions are case sensitive! - New to python!!

Comment: how does this answer change if my library is installed in editable mode e.g. `pip install -e .`?

Comment: for me it seems that deleting the `.idea` folder fixed everything. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66701106/1601580

Comment: @PuffinGDI why does having the `__init__.py` matter? I believe I've not put them in the past and when I run code it still is able to find the other folders and packages inside of the main pkg folder.

Comment: @CharlieParker Why is the bounty on this question and not on your new question? Is this question the one you're trying to get answered (The one with an accepted answer with nearly 1000 upvotes) or is it your other one you want answered? Putting it here means I need to go through 25 answers, multiple posts, 8 years of answers, and it's not clear what I'm even trying to answer

Comment: @nanotek I believe I have to wait 2 days before placing a bounty on new questions. I sympathize with you. The answers here didn't work for me. But to answer mine even with a bounty, wouldn't you need to go through lots of answers anyway? If you answer mine I promise to reward you if it works :)

Comment: one more thing to watch out is the name of the production code file. If you have hyphens (-) rather than underscores (_), test class will fail to import them.

Answer (score 1145, accepted):

Manually adding it as you have done *is* indeed one way of doing this, but there is a simpler method, and that is by simply telling pycharm that you want to add the `src` folder as a source root, and then adding the sources root to your python path.

This way, you don't have to hard code things into your interpreter's settings:

- Add `src` as a source content root:

[image]

- Then make sure to add add sources to your `PYTHONPATH` under:

  ```
  Preferences ~ Build, Execution, Deployment ~ Console ~ Python Console
  ```

[image]

- Now imports will be resolved:

[image]

This way, you can add whatever you want as a source root, and things will simply work. If you unmarked it as a source root however, you *will* get an error:

[image]

After all this don't forget to restart. In PyCharm menu select: File --> Invalidate Caches / Restart

Comment: This also works if you're using the Python plugin with IntelliJ.

Comment: This solution works. The problem of it is that when another programmer retrieves the code from svn, she has to do the same settings again to get rid of the "unresolved reference" error prompt.

Comment: @BenLin True, however for all other solutions you would have to do the same.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac, the solution is that the IDE can parse "sys.path.insert(0, "./src")" add that into PYTHONPATH for this specific file, then give proper syntax analysis.

Comment: You also need to make sure your content root path is correct.  In pycharm 5 you can find this in Preferences -> Project -> Project Structure.

Comment: Strangely, sub-directories are not taken into account. For example, if under `src`, we have `views` folder inside which I have `myview.py`, I still receive unresolved reference error when trying `from src.views.myview import <my_function>`...

Comment: Just for the record: if you're using django, the root folder should be that one named `projectName` with the `manage.py` inside (not that one with virtual env etc.)

Comment: I had to make my "trunk" folder (in SVN) the Source Root.  Then it worked for me.  When I tried the folder above that; it didn't work for some odd reason.

Comment: This works great. I just had to add multiple folders as source route. thanks

Comment: The solution provided by @robmayoff works, too. Installed Python plugins and the issue has gone away. Thanks

Comment: In `IntelliJ IDEA 2016+` this option has been relocated; see [**@AeroHil**'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43433438/3679900)

Comment: What is the difference if you do the second step of adding sources to PYTHONPATH or not? Are both step 1 (add src as source content root) and step 2 (add sources to PYTHONPATH) necessary under all circumstances?

Comment: why was this a problem?

Comment: how does this answer change if my library is installed in editable mode e.g. `pip install -e .`?

Comment: for me it seems that deleting the `.idea` folder fixed everything. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66701106/1601580

Comment: my `PYTHONPATH ` is empty, is that normal?

Comment: Phew, that invalidated cache and restart did the charm!

Answer (score 77):

1. check for `__init__.py` file in `src` folder
2. add the `src` folder as a source root
3. Then make sure to add sources to your `PYTHONPATH` (see above)
4. in PyCharm menu select: File --> Invalidate Caches --> Restart

Comment: This very last step was the only thing missing in my solution. The accepted answer might add this to it.

Comment: without the last step mentioned here, the accepted answer is not working. Accepted answer should add this step as well/

Comment: how does this answer change if my library is installed in editable mode e.g. `pip install -e .`?

Comment: my `PYTHONPATH ` is empty, is that normal?

Answer (score 34):

If anyone is still looking at this, the accepted answer still works for PyCharm 2016.3 when I tried it. The UI might have changed, but the options are still the same.

ie. Right click on your root folder --> 'Mark Directory As' --> Source Root

Comment: So many complex answers in this discussion. The solution presented here worked for me so easily.

Comment: what does "root folder" mean for you? Like the root of the github repo or the package root e.g. something like `src`?

Comment: my `PYTHONPATH ` is empty, is that normal?

Comment: Thanks. This worked like a "charm" pun intended :)

Comment: Best and easy solution

Answer (score 21):

After testing all workarounds, i suggest you to take a look at `Settings -> Project -> project dependencies` and re-arrange them.

[image: pycharm prefrence]

Comment: This works perfectly for me. I have installed `pygame` there and not more unresolved reference issue!

Comment: how am I suppose to re-arrange them?

Comment: This solution works in my case. @CharlieParker  Suppose you work on module2, and module2 relies on module1. In that case, make sure module2 depends on module1 in `Settings -> Project -> project dependencies` section.

Answer (score 15):

Normally, [$PYTHONPATH is used to teach python interpreter to find necessary modules](http://jettify.net/2012/pythonpath/). PyCharm needs to add the path in Preference.

[image]

Comment: how do I check if my python paths are set up correctly? currently, my `PYTHONPATH` is empty. I am not sure why this wasn't setup by itself correctly. Btw, the link you share is not working.

Comment: I can't see the python Paths box that your picture shows in 2021.3 version...

Comment: my `PYTHONPATH ` is empty, is that normal?

Answer (score 9):

There are several reasons why this could be happening. Below are several steps that fixes the majority of those cases:

**.idea caching issue**

Some `.idea` issue causing the IDE to show error while the code still runs correctly. Solution:

1. close the project and quick PyCharm
2. delete the `.idea` folder where the project is. note that it is a hidden folder and you might not be aware of its existence in your project directory.
3. start PyCharm and recreate the project

**imports relative not to project folder**

Relative imports while code root folder is not the same as the project folder. Solution:

1. Find the folder that relative imports require in the project explorer
2. right click and mark it as "Source Root"

**Editor not marking **init**.py as Python but as Text**

Which is the most illusive of all the cases. Here, for some reason, PyCharm considers all `__init__.py` files not to be python files, and thus ignores them during code analysis. To fix this:

1. Open PyCharm settings
2. Navigate to Editor -> File Types
3. Find Python and add `__init__.py` to the list of python files

or

3. Find Text and delete `__init__.py` from the list of text files

Comment: how do I find the `.idea` folder?

Comment: Answering my own question, I went to the root of my project (not src but say the git repo root folder). Then I did `rm -rf .idea`. Then restarted pycharm. I really puzzled why this worked...so far. At least the ide is finding the files and the running of the code does too (but that always worked even when running from within pycharm e.g. with the debugger).

Comment: why does this work?

Comment: btw, is recreating the project really necessary?

Comment: Recreating the project happens automatically when starting PyCharm in that folder. That will re-creates the .idea folder that stores project settings, the string search index and other things.

Comment: To find the `.idea` folder use `ls -a` to list all files and folders including hidden one (that start with a dot). To see the content of the .idea folder you can use the terminal to `cd` into it the `ls` as usual.

Comment: Why does refreshing the cache works for you? Well it could be that the cache is outdated and because of some glitch in PyCharm or some change you made to the project, the cache was not refreshed and functions and classes and packages names lookup table was not refreshed. When running the code, Python interpret your code in real time (almost) and that part has nothing to do with PyCharm. PyCharm is just a fancy text editor in this case.

Comment: Anyway I am happy recreating the .idea folder worked for you…!

Comment: Hi Ouss, thanks for your kind replies. It is sad, it actually doesn't work consistently for some reason :(. Now that I changed file in my project it cannot find the reference to the projects source root `src`. So I am puzzled why it's not working. It has worked with other laptops out of the box as long as I activate the conda env. Might it be that? I also had some issues earlier with the `PATH` env variable so I wonder if it's that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240111/discussion-between-charlie-parker-and-ouss).

Answer (score 7):

The project I cloned had a directory called `modules` and was successfully using files from there in the code with `import this as that`, but Pycharm was unable to jump to those code fragments because it did not recognise the imports.

**Marking the module folder** in the following settings section as `source` solved the issue.

[image: Pycharm Preferences]

Answer (score 6):

Although all the answers are really helpful, there's one tiny piece of information that should be explained explicitly:

- Essentially, a project with multiple hierarchical directories work as a package with some attributes.
- To import custom local created Classes, we need to navigate to the directory containing `.py` file and create an `__init__.py` (empty) file there.

Why this helps is because this file is required to make Python treat the directory as containing packages. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Generally, this is a missing package problem, just place the caret at the unresolved reference and press `Alt+Enter` to reveal the options, then you should know how to solve it.

Comment: what is alt+enter in mac?

Answer (score 3):

Install via PyCharm (works with Community Edition). Open up `Settings > Project > Project Interpreter` then click the green + icon in the screenshot below. In the 2nd dialogue that opens, enter the package name and click the 'Install Package' button.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

After following the accepted answer, doing the following solved it for me:

`File` → `Settings` → `Project <your directory/project>` → `Project Dependencies`

Chose the directory/project where your file that has unresolved imports resides and check the box to tell Pycharm that that project depends on your other project.

My folder hierarcy is slightly different from the one in the question. Mine is like this

```
├── MyDirectory  
│     └── simulate.py  
├── src  
│     ├── networkAlgorithm.py  
│     ├── ...
```

Telling Pycharm that src depends on `MyDirectory` solved the issue for me!

Answer (score 2):

Many a times what happens is that the plugin is not installed. e.g.

If you are developing a django project and you do not have django plugin installed in pyCharm, it says error 'unresolved reference'. 
Refer:
https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/resolving-references.html

Comment: Had to combine this + the accepted answer(https://stackoverflow.com/a/21241988/6448384).

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me: `Top Menu -> File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart`

Answer (score 2):

1. --> Right-click on the directory where your files are located in PyCharm
2. Go to the --> Mark Directory as
3. Select the --> Source Root

your problem will be solved

Answer (score 2):

I was also using a virtual environment like Dan above, however I was able to add an interpreter in the existing environment, therefore not needing to inherit global site packages and therefore undo what a virtual environment is trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you are using the right interpreter that you are supposed to. I was getting error "unresolved reference 'django' " to solve this I changed Project Interpreter (Changed Python 3 to Python 2.7) from project settings:
Select Project, go to File -> Settings -> Project: -> Project Interpreter -> Brows and Select correct version or Interpreter (e.g /usr/bin/python2.7).

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was I was using `Virtual environment` which didn't have access to global site-packages. Thus, the interpreter was not aware of the newly installed packages.

To resolve the issue, just edit or recreate your virtual interpreter and tick the `Inherit global site-packages` option.

[image]

Comment: Doesnt this have undesirable consequences and defeat one reason to use a virtual environement?  That is, if you take that environment somewhere and those global site-packages are installed, then you are in trouble.  Thats what i thought.

Answer (score 1):

Done in PyCharm 2019.3.1
**Right-click on your src folder -> "Mark Directory as" -> Click-on "Excluded"** and your src folder should be blue.

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything here twice and even more. I finally solved it doing something I hadn't seen anywhere online.  If you go to `Settings>Editor>File Types` there is an `'Ignore Files and folders`' line at the bottom.  In my case, I was ignoring `'venv'`, which is what I always name my virtual environments.  So I removed `venv;` from the list of directories to ignore and VOILA!!  I was FINALLY able to fix this problem.  Literally all of my import problems were fixed for the project.

BTW, I had installed each and every package using PyCharm, and not through a terminal. (Meaning, by going to `Settings>Interpreter...`). I had invalidated cache, changed 'Source Root', restarted PyCharm, refreshed my interpreters paths, changed interpreters, deleted my venv...  I tried everything.  This finally worked. Obviously there are multiple problems going on here with different people, so this may not work for you, but it's definitely worth a shot if nothing else has worked, and easy to reverse if it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

For my case :

```
Directory0
    ├── Directory1
    │     └── file1.py  
    ├── Directory2
    │     ├── file2.py
```

Into file1, I have :

```
from Directory2 import file2
```

which trows an "unresolved reference Directory2".

I resolved it by:

- marking the parent directory Directory0 as "Source Root" like said above

**AND**

- putting my cursor on another line on the file where I had the error so that it takes my modification into account

It is silly but if I don't do the second action, the error still appears and can make you think that you didn't resolve the issue by marking the parent directory as Source Root.

Comment: I've just added the parent folder i.e. Directory0 (in this case) and this just worked for me, had been struggling for days on this issue, thank you so much

Comment: The change applied in my case after I restarted pyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

For me, adding virtualenv (`venv`)'s site-packages path to the paths of the interpreter works.
Finally!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and also try so many suggestions but none of them worked, until I find this post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/62632870/16863617). Regardless his solution didn't work for me, it helped me to came up with the idea to add **_*init.py***_ into the --> **Settings | Editor | File Types | Python | Registered patterns**

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkBD9.png)

And the unresolved reference error is now solved.

Answer (score 0):

just note if u have a problem with python interpreter not installing
packages, just change the permission for folder **PycharmProjects**
C:\Users'username'\PycharmProjects
to *every one*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This problem also appears if you use a dash within the Python filename, which therefore is strongly discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered an import problem when installing aiogram. At the same time, the bot worked, but pyCharm highlighted the import in red and did not give hints. I've tried all of the above many times.As a result, the following helped me: I found the **aiogram** folder at the following path
***c\Users...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages***
and copied it to the folder
***C:\Program Files\Python310\Lib\site-packages***
After that, I reset pyCharm and that's it!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, with Pycharm 2019.3, the problem was that I forgot to add the extension '.py' to the file I wanted to import. Once added, the error went away without needing to invalides caches or any other step.

Answer (score -1):

Pycharm uses venv. In the venv's console you should install the packages explicitly or go in `settings -> project interpreter -> add interpreter -> inherit global site-packages`.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to fix it is by doing the following in your pyCharm software:

Click on: File > Settings > (Project: your project name) > Project Interpreter >

then click on the "+" icon on the right side to search for the package you want and install it.

Enjoy coding !!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thanks for your answer. Whilst this may be correct, in the future please avoid posting images or links to other sites without context or further details. The link may stop working at some point, making this answer less useful for other users.

Comment: @CyberJacob Thank you very much, and thanks a lot for your advice, I've edited the answer by removing the image and adding text instead.

Answer (score -2):

In newer versions of pycharm u can do simply by right clicking on the directory or python package from which you want to import a file, then click on 'Mark Directory As' -> 'Sources Root'