# Python - ImportError: cannot import name 'HelloW'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have a folder called pack1, and two python files called Task1 and HelloW. For some reason I'm getting this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'HelloW'
```

Here is the code:

```
# file HelloW
class HelloW:
    name = "John Doe"

    def print_hello(self):
        print("Hello, %s" % self.name)


#file Task1
from pack1 import HelloW

hw = HelloW()
hw.print_hello()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest renaming HelloW.py to hellow.py (according to http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names modules and packages should have all-lowercase names).

Then try updating your import statement to import the `HelloW` class from `hellow` module:

```
from hellow import HelloW
```

Comment: Nvm, I found answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236824/unresolved-reference-issue-in-pycharm

Answer (score 0):

Try to create an empty file called `__init__.py` in your pack1 directory.

Comment: Doesn't fix the problem. Also in addition to this, I'm using an IDE PyCharm, it highlights my line hw = HelloW() with a yellow color, with a message when i hover over 'HelloW' is not callable