# How to lemmatize spanish words with Pattern?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk, text-classification

I would like to lemmatize a bunch of opinions. As I know, nltk cannot lemmatize words in languages different from English. Researching a little, I found [pattern](http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pattern), which can lemmatize words in several languages. How can I lemmatize some text with pattern?

This is my test corpus:

```
# -- coding: utf-8 --

from pattern.es import lemma #unresolved reference

opinions = ["Este es un post de juguetes de aprendizaje \
automático. En realidad, contiene no mucho \
material interesante.",
"Las bases de datos de imágenes proporcionan \
capacidades de almacenamiento.",
"La mayoría de las bases de datos de imágenes \
imágenes seguras de forma permanente.",
"Los datos de imagen de tienda bases de datos.",
"Imagina almacenar bases de datos de bases de \
datos de imágenes. Almacenar datos. Bases de datos \
de imágenes de datos de la tienda."]

print lemma(opiniones)
```

output:

```
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Pruebas/Lemmatizacion.py", line 18, in <module>
    print lemma(opiniones)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pattern/text/__init__.py", line 1591, in lemma
    if verb.lower() in self._inverse:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

How can I lemmatize `opinions`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can lemmatize text using pattern's parsetree function with the lemmata parameter set to True.

```
from pattern.es import parsetree
parsetree("buena", lemmata=True)
# Returns [Sentence('buena/JJ/B-ADJP/O/bueno')]
```

Comment: When i import parsetree i have an unresolved reference, how can i solve this?

Comment: In that case you probably have not properly installed/configured the pattern library. Is this PyCharm error the type of "unresolved reference" you're referring to? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236824/unresolved-reference-issue-in-pycharm

Comment: Thank you nathan, i followed the instructions and i still having problems with the unresolved reference. What can i do?..

Comment: Documentation for Pattern (see the Sentence section for use of parsetree): https://www.clips.uantwerpen.be/pages/pattern-en . Basic usage: `pt = parsetree("buenos dias", lemmata=True) for sentence in pt: 
    for lemmata in sentence.lemmata:
        print lemmata`