# Selenium Webdriver import

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Super basic question, but when I try to import the webdriver from selenium I get a message "Unresolved reference".

```
 from selenium import webdriver
 chrome_path = "/Users/username/downloads/chromedriver"
 driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unresolved reference issue in PyCharm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236824/unresolved-reference-issue-in-pycharm)

Comment: Have you installed Selenium Python bindings correctly? I recommend to read this page: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#simple-usage

Comment: run `pip freeze` command and check whether selenium is installed or not. also mention python, selenium and chrome versions.