# From psycopg2 import sql not working

Tags: pycharm, python-3.5, psycopg2

Looking for some help with an issue I am having with psycopg2 and Python3. I am trying to use the sql library from psycopg2 that is available in version 2.7.1. 
When trying to use

```
from psycopg2 import sql
```

I get the error message unresolved reference 'sql'

I am using Xubuntu Linux 16.04 LTS and when issuing the command

```
pip show psycopg2
```

in the terminal I get:

```
Name: psycopg2

Version: 2.7.1
Summary: psycopg2 - Python-PostgreSQL Database Adapter

Home-page: http://initd.org/psycopg/

Author: Federico Di Gregorio

Author-email: fog@initd.org

License: LGPL with exceptions or ZPL

Location: /home/bigdaddy/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages

Requires:
```

So it appears to be installed in my system. Also in Pycharm when I go to
File -> Settings -> Project Interpreter..
I see psycopg2 2.7.1 installed there as well.
Any ideas of what is going on and why I am unable to use the psycopg2 sql functionality in my project? Everything appears to be installed to me it seems. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

That is a common issue in PyCharm, follow those instructions: [Unresolved reference issue in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236824/unresolved-reference-issue-in-pycharm?answertab=votes#tab-top) and you will eliminate the problem!

For the case that the link does not work:

1. Right click on your root project folder.
2. In the tab that appears, find the *Mark Directory as*.
3. In the expansion window that shows up, click the *Sources root*

Comment: Thanks for your time and answers and link. I am still having this issue after following the suggestion you provided and other things found in the link. One thing I did try that I previously have not, was File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart but still no luck. I will keep digging.