# How to handle popup window by using python automation

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am using Selenium Webdriver with Python for automation testing. While login my application I have got popup message for clicking 'OK' button. where i have used

```
from selenium import webdriver 
def cbs_login(): 
    browser = webdriver.Firefox() 
    browser.get('172.20.31.1:7085/web/ccp/login') 
    user = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#userid') 
    user.send_keys('admin') 
    password = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#password')
    password.send_keys('admin2') 
    login_location = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#loginlocation') 
    login_location.click() 
    location_name = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div‌​/div/div/form/div/di‌​v/div/div/table/tbod‌​y/tr[4]/td/select/op‌​tion[3]')     
    location_name.click() 
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept(); 
    cbs_login()
```

i can't use the code ,I am getting error like "unresolved reference" Please mention is there any alternate way to handle it by python 2.7 version.

Comment: what is name of variable of driver

Comment: i searched from internet and used this driver command. am not sure about it.

Comment: can you post complete script

Comment: from selenium import webdriver
def cbs_login():
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.get('http://172.20.31.1:7085/web/ccp/login')
    user = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#userid')
    user.send_keys('admin')
    password = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#password')

Comment: password.send_keys('admin2')
    login_location = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#loginlocation')
    login_location.click()
    location_name = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/form/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/select/option[3]')
    location_name.click()
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
cbs_login()

Comment: i am just a beginner so i might commit lot of mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`switchTo()` is not a `Python` method. You should try

```
browser.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

Also make sure that you have [correctly import WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236824/unresolved-reference-issue-in-pycharm)

Answer (score 0):

Please replace driver in as told by @andersson

```
driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

as browser and try

```
browser.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

Comment: Thanks :) now i can handle popup window. But now i am facing another problem . while login i have to select my location which will display in drop down. i am providing which drown want to select in the script , it is selecting the location but it is not displaying in location box. please help on this by checking my given code before

Comment: @Sarwan, try to implement code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867537/selenium-python-drop-down-menu-option-value/28613320#28613320)

Comment: @Andresson, I tried with that scenario, in this i cont able to select the location itself. :(

Comment: from selenium import webdriver from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select def cbs_login(): browser = webdriver.Firefox() browser.get('url') user = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#userid') user.send_keys('admin') password = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#password') password.send_keys('admin2') select = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#loginlocation') select.click() select.select_by_visible_text('WAREHOUSE')  browser.switch_to.alert.accept(); cbs_login()

Comment: @Sarwan. You implemented it incorrectly. Try `select = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('loginlocation'))  select.select_by_visible_text('WAREHOUSE')`