# Pycharm: unresolved reference after installing package

Tags: python, pycharm

I installed a package via Pycharm and it still highlights Api as unresolved. What is wrong here?

```
from flask.ext.restful import Api
```

[image]

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236824/unresolved-reference-issue-in-pycharm

Comment: `from flask_restful import ...` is used in the [guide](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html)