# nameError when trying to assign a function's return value to a variable. How can resolve this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

```
def evaluate():
    a=2
    return a

print(evaluate())
```

Then im getting "unresolved reference" in the pycharm where the `evaluate()` in print function is underlined in red color.

Comment: Your code is fine. It's hard to tell why your IDE thinks it isn't.

Comment: You need to add source directory, if `evaluate()` not in current directory.

Comment: It returns 2 on my machine. Your code has no problem at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unresolved reference issue in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236824/unresolved-reference-issue-in-pycharm)

Comment: I'm running PyCharm 2018.1.1 on Ubuntu... There are no errors from this code. After I fix your PEP8 problems, there are no warnings either (spaces around the assignment operator, double line between the function and print).  /usr/test/venv/bin/python /usr/pycharm-2018.1.1/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 39627 --file /usr/test/blah.py
pydev debugger: process 37851 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 181.4445.76)
2

Process finished with exit code 0