# Unresolved reference 'addresses' in Pycharm Community Edition

Tags: django

[My Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8O4g.jpg)     [My Pycharm Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stynl.jpg)

Hello, if you can see the attached screenshot of my Django project in Pycharm, you'll see that all the imports from other app folders have a red underline. When I hover mouse on them, it says "Unresolved reference 'addresses'". 
All the apps have been added to settings.py and the project is running fine without any errors. The red underlines are really bugging me though. What can I do to get rid of them? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Oh I think I found the solution. Similar problem has been answered here
[Unresolved reference issue in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236824/unresolved-reference-issue-in-pycharm?rq=1)

I will leave my post up in case anyone else is having the same issue.