# PyCharm gives "unresolved reference" message, but can run the code

Tags: python, pycharm

I am running PyCharm 2019.2.5 with a toy example. I have the following directory structure:

```
├── main.py
├── a_package
│   ├── a_module.py
```

My `a_module.py` file looks like this:

```
class a_class:

    def __init__(self):
        self.a_variable = 5
```

And my `main.py` file looks like this:

```
from a_package import a_module

x = a_module.a_class()
print(x.a_variable)
```

Running `main.py` outputs `5`. This is as expected. However, I have a couple of questions about all of this.

1) In `main.py`, in the line `from a_package import a_module`, both `a_package` and `a_module` have a red line underneath in PyCharm. Hovering over this reveals "Unresolved reference 'a_package'" and "Unresolved reference 'a_module'". Why is this happening? PyCharm is clearly able to find these files, since the code runs ok.

I have also tried adding the directory `a_package` to the "Sources" in "Settings -> Project -> Project Structure". However, this does not affect anything. PyCharm still gives me a message saying that it cannot find these references. According to the PyCharm documentation on the source roots, "These roots contain the actual source files and resources. PyCharm uses the source roots as the starting point for resolving imports." So, even after adding this directory to the source root, it is strange that it is giving me this error / warning. Why is this happening?

2) I often see a similar structure to the above, but with an empty `__init__` file as follows:

```
├── main.py
├── a_package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── a_module.py
```

My understanding is that this makes `a_package` an actual Python package, whereas before it is just a directory containing Python files. But why would this be done? Why can I not just have it as I originally had it, without the `__init__` file, and just import the module as I did above?

Comment: This looks similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236824/unresolved-reference-issue-in-pycharm). Do the answers there help?

Comment: As suggested in that answer, I have added `a_package` to the source roots (as I state above). And by default, "Add source roots to PYTHONPATH" is already checked by default. So, the answer to that question didn't help.

Comment: Try rebuilding skeletons after having set the interpreter, etc. You can find this under `File` - `Invalidate Caches/Restart`, and then hit `Invalidate and Restart` (this usually fixes all sorts of issues for me).

Comment: This didn’t work for me unfortunately. The red lines still appear.

Answer (score 1):

1) When PyCharm's warnings bug (although it is not frequent), you can fix it by cuting the code and then pasting it. You can also try to restart PyCharm.

2)

> My understanding is that this makes a_package an actual Python
>   package, whereas before it is just a directory containing Python files

I agree with you on this point.

I am able to import modules without a __init__ file so you should be able to as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with PyCharm, not with python itself, that's why you're able to run it.
Select the root folder of your sources (presumably src), right-click and select Mark Directory As -> Sources Root.

Comment: This didn’t work for me unfortunately. I have tried setting all directories as sources root, but I still get the red lines.