# Selenium Framework problem import file .py - PyCharm python

Tags: python, pycharm

This is my project:

---

In Pages.py After import file , work fine there are red line under file why ?

---

In .py After import file Locators.py and .py, and like photo Everything work fine but there are red line under file why ?

and this line:

Comment: What does it say when you hover over those red underlines?

Comment: -from Locators import Locators
Unresolved reference 'Locators' , after click more action I see , Rename Reference or convert to 'import Locators'.
-from TestData import TestData
Unresolved reference 'TestData', after click more action I see ,Install Packages TestData and Rename Reference or convert to 'import Locators'.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. check for `__init__.py` file in `src` folder
2. add the `src` folder as a source root
3. Then make sure to add additional sources to your `PYTHONPATH`
4. in PyCharm menu select: File --> Invalidate Caches / Restart

Point `4` generally fixes the `unresolved reference errors`. If that doesn't work then see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21241988/6505847). It contains many solutions that you may try.

If nothing has worked, then you can just turn off the red underline by going to

> File->Settings->Editor->Inspections

From there simply untick the relevant error.

**A side note:** It's always best to place your imports right at the top.

Comment: if this answer helped solve your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information