# PyCharm unresolved reference for module members

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a flask app that I'm developing in PyCharm on MacOS.

When I try to import the flask current app like this:

```
from flask import current_app as app
```

I get an inspection error: `Unresolved reference 'current_app'`, but when I run the the project I get no runtime errors.

If I "import" the current app like this:

```py
import flask
app = flask.current_app
```

then PyCharm is happy.

I have the same problem with local imports. How can I fix this.

Comment: Note that this is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236824/unresolved-reference-issue-in-pycharm because I have no problem importing the module in the first place

Comment: what about if your first line is `from flask import current_app` and your second line is 'app = current_app' ?

Comment: @rajah9, that doesn't work either :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I opened a ticket with JetBrains support, and after a long investigation they found the issue.

Somehow my `__init__.py` files got associated with text files, and that broke the resolver. I fixed it by going to **Settings | Editor | File Types | Text | Registered patterns** and deleting `__init__.py` from the registered patterns.

Thank you JetBrains for the great support!

Answer (score 1):

I tried the solution that the user nobody suggested. However, the file __init__.py was not within the Registered Patterns in the Text file type.

I searched lot of similar questions and also tried their suggestions but nothing worked. So I came up with the idea to add __init__.py into the --> **Settings | Editor | File Types | Python | Registered patterns**

[image: Ss]

And the unresolved reference error is now solved.