# I get an unresolved reference error when I try to use the package

Tags: python

i tried to use example1.py as a package but i got unresolved reference error. how can i fix the error.

you can see below the folder structure:

```
PycharmProjects
├── first_folder
│   └── example1.py
│       __init__.py
└── second_folder
    └── example2.py
```

```
# example1.py
def example_1():
  return None
```

```
# example2.py
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/user/PycharmProjects/')
from first_folder.example1 import example_1
# i am getting an error at above part
```

Comment: @gakowiw869, can you post the exact error you are getting?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf Unresolved reference 'first_folder'

Comment: This seems to be a PyCharm warning, not a Python error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unresolved reference issue in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236824/unresolved-reference-issue-in-pycharm)