# How to set PyCharm project structure to avoid unresolved reference error?

Tags: python, pycharm, python-import

I have specific project structure

```
- src
  - common/
    - constants/
      - __init__.py
    - database.py
  - user
    - create/
      - main.py
      - constants/
        - app_constants.py
        - __init__.py
```

I made common directory source root.

In main.py I have

```
from common import database
from constants import app_constants
```

Second import is showing `Unresolved reference 'constants'`

How to set PyCharm project structure to fix it?

Comment: You are importing a module from a package, you're supposed to import classes/functions not the whole module. `app_constants` is a file, `app_constants.py` the import would work if there where an object in the `constants/__init__.py` called `app_constants`. So your import should be `from constants.app_constants import something`.

Comment: Besides that mistake set `src` as the ["sources root" in the IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21241988/)