# pyton import statement not resolving

Tags: function, import

I am doing online training for python and django for API's.
-I created a project folder that has my firstProject.  Note:  the server started fine.
-I created an app called:  firstApp in a folder beside firstProject.
when I try to write the import statement to import a function from firstApp to a views.py in firstProject; it doesn't resolve.  Can someone help me with this?  I tried to "Mark Directory" for firstApp as src and made sure the settings were correct, and restarted python, but that didn't resolve the issue. Here are some print screens.  If there is anything else you would like to see please let me know.

I took this directly from the training.  the trainer is using ATOM, but he said we can use any IDE so I am most comfortable with pycharm.

[image]

My function is called display in the views.py file in firstApp/views.py

```
def display(request):
return HttpResponse("<h1>My First App!!!<h1>")
```

[image]

Here is my code that is not resolving from firstProject/urls.py:

```
from firstApp import views
```

[image]

I referenced this url when trying to "Mark directory" as src:
[Unresolved reference issue in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236824/unresolved-reference-issue-in-pycharm/21241988#21241988)

If anyone can give me some ideas of what I should do to fix this; that would be fantastic!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The fix to this was to "Mark directory" as src to the firstProject, firstApp, and firstProject.

Then restart pycharm